# Mac/iOS chess app with rates option

Tags: engines, software

I am looking for a chess app that you can set an exact rate to play against the computer (same as you have in chess.com where you set it to play against others).

Is there any Mac (specifically) and iOS app where you can:

1. play computer and choose the exact rate of the computer
2. have some kind of analysis of your game

It must be an offline app.

Comment: Welcome to Chess.SE! Do you mean rate (as in 'time control') or rating ('playing strength')?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend my own iOS app, [SmallChess](http://www.smallchess.com) and [SmallFish](http://www.smallchess.com). They have time controls and playing strength.

In addition, there are many many other similar apps on the market. A simple "chess" keyword search in the app store will give you many results.

For MacOS, the [Stockfish MacOSX](http://stockfishchess.org/mac/) program is good.